# Recursively search sub directories, ignore directories PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

I am using AJAX and a text input to send a search string to my current PHP file, this script searches the directory for files and folders but no sub folders. What I would like is something that searches only for files in the directory and sub directory and then lists them. Structure like this:

```
Corecube
-Categories
--Movies
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
--Music
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
--Pictures
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
-MainCategories
--Code
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
--Gifs
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
```

And then the search takes place in the parent of "Corecube" but spits out only file names from each sub directory without the actual directories. I have tried a few iterations of my current script but end up breaking it every time.

```
<?php
    $dir = "../corecube";
    $key = $_GET['key'];

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
      if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
          if($file == $key){
            echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
          }
        }
      closedir($dh);
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> **UPDATED CODE FORMAT:**

you need to search file in nested folder

try this

```
<?php 
function matchFile($filename, $path, $key) 
{  
    if(preg_match("/$key/i",$filename)) 
    {       
        echo('<a href="'.$path.'">'. $filename .'</a>'."<br>"); //use regex than casual '==' for flexible search    
    } 
}

function getListDir($dir, $key) 
{   
    if(strlen($key)<2) die("insert min 2 length string"); //for avoid return/display bunch of list file     
    if(is_dir($dir))    
    {       
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) 
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
            {
                $newItem="$dir/$file";
                if($file=='.' || $file=="..")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                elseif(is_dir("$newItem"))
                {
                    getListDir("$newItem", $key);
                }
                elseif(is_file("$newItem"))
                {
                    matchFile($file, $newItem, $key);
                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }           
        }           
        else            
        {
            die ("cant open folder: $folder");          
        }   
    } 
}

//run script 
$initialFolder="initialfolder"; // change this into "../corecube"
$key = (isset($_GET["key"]))?$_GET['key']:NULL; 
getListDir($initialFolder, $key); 
?>
```

Comment: thats why this worked script was downvoted. posting from android apps can change code format. now i already fix it